# Recursive struct

Tags: c, struct, recursive-datastructures

Do I need to use `typedef` in order to build recursive structs? I tried to use the following code without success:

```
struct teste
{
    int data;
    int data2;
    struct teste to_teste;
};
```

Comment: Why do you use the keyword struct twice?

Comment: You can't have directly recursive structures in C; they require an infinite amount of storage space.  You can have structures that contain pointers to themselves.

Comment: I tried to define struct inside a struct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To build recursive structs you do not need `typedef`.

You will have to convert the struct object into a `struct pointer` object.

like this:

```
struct teste{
  int data;
  int data2;
  struct teste *to_teste;
};
```

Comment: @user1843665 that's what stack overflow is for. :-)

Comment: Oh, i see.I would make a reference to data2 in the inner struct by : 
    struct teste testing; 
    testing.to_teste->data2 ?

Comment: don't forget to `malloc()` the `to_teste` pointer before using `testing.to_teste->data2;`

Answer (score 6):

You CANNOT have the same structure inside itself. If you do that then size of that structure becomes indefinite. So that is not allowed.

Instead you can have a pointer to the same structure inside itself to solve your purpose. This will work because size of a pointer is known to the compiler and the structure has a definite size now.